# Explicit wait not working while using MobileElement

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

I am using appium to automate a android mobile application. I am finding elements using accessibility id. When the app launches, i want to click on a login button. Here s how i located that element.

```
@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "loginButton")
    public MobileElement loginButton;
```

I have a explicit wait method as follows:

```
public void waitUntilElementIsVisible(MobileElement id) {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(id));
}
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
waitUntilElementIsVisible(loginLocators.loginButton).click();
```

But when the tests starts, its not able to find the login button and gives me 'NoSuchElementError'. The output logs:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/ffa63718-deb5-4e15-8cd7-74363f2c084f/element
[HTTP] {"using":"accessibility id","value":"loginButton"}
[debug] [W3C (ffa63718)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["accessibility id","loginButton","ffa63718-deb5-4e15-8cd7-74363f2c084f"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:51197/wd/hub/session/5043b2ed-8ea9-4394-a074-353004a6a1f6/element] with body: {"strategy":"accessibility id","selector":"loginButton","context":"","multiple":false}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"5043b2ed-8ea9-4394-a074-353004a6a1f6","value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:70)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:41)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:261)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:255)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)\n\tat io.netty.chann...
[debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such element' to NoSuchElementError
[debug] [W3C (ffa63718)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
[debug] [W3C (ffa63718)]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/find.js:75:11)
[debug] [W3C (ffa63718)]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/ffa63718-deb5-4e15-8cd7-74363f2c084f/element 404 29 ms - 460
```

It works fine with implicit waits and thread.sleep(). But due to some reasons, i want to use explicit waits.

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return type of the method to WebElement :

```
public WebElement waitUntilElementIsVisible(MobileElement id) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(id));
}
```